# IBM Rational Doors Linking two objects within the same module and save it to a baseline

Tags: ibm-doors

Can't seem to find any documentation on if this is a limitation or known issue.

I have two objects (Obj1 and Obj2) that live in the same module (Module A). I can link Obj1 -> Obj2 just fine on the current version of the Module. So Obj1 shows an outlink to Obj2 and Obj2 shows a inlink from Obj1.

Now when I create a baseline of Module A and view that created baseline the links between Obj1 and Obj2 are gone.

Can't seem to figure out why that's happening.

Comment: I cannot confirm this. I open a module with at least 2 objects, create links from obj 1 to obj 2 as said, save the module, close/reopen it -> links are there. Create a baseline 1.0. Open current version -> links are there. Open the baseline that I just created (same major, minor, suffix) -> links are there. right click on outgoing link, says ...Module [1.0] -> 2.

Sounds like a severe bug to me or something different. Which version do you use? Mine is 9.7.2.2

Answer (score 1):

To baseline links you need to create a baseline set. In DOORS 9, baseline sets are stored on folders/projects. Right click on a folder and there will be a tab called "Baseline Set Definitions". This is where you will create a new definition where you add the module(s) you want included in the set. You will then create a new baseline set using the "Baseline Set" tab on the same dialog box. This will baseline all of the modules in the set, along with links.